# Swift - Refencing object in an array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, uicollectionview

I have a collection view where I'm trying to display the following:

```
"Group A" (header)
Cat 1
Cat 2
Cat 3

"Group B" (header)
Cat 4
Cat 5
Cat 6

"Group C" (header)
Cat 7
Cat 8
Cat 9
```

My data source is defined like this:

```
var sections = [[String:[Cat]]]()
```

This part is straightforward:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}
```

I know there should be an easy way to do this, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to display each Cat object:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CatCell", for: indexPath) as! CatCollectionViewCell
    let section = sections[indexPath.section]
    let cats = section.values
    let cat = cats[indexPath.row] //Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Dictionary<String, [Cat]>.Index'
    cell.configure(with: cat)
    return cell
}
```

How do I properly determine the Cat at this index path?

Comment: Dictionaries are unsuitable as table/collection view data sources because the order of their entries is unspecified.

Comment: To get rid of the error you need to convert the Dictionary values to an Array, `let cats = Array(section.values)`

Comment: @MartinR it's an array of dictionaries though. I'm just using the dictionary to store the title of each group along with its objects.

Comment: You could use a struct with a title property and the array of cats to use for your array instead of a dictionary, otherwise see my previous comment. The struct solution would be cleaner IMO

Comment: @soleil Or an array of Tuples. Nothing is gained with the dictionary and it leads to confusion.

Comment: Definitely calls for a struct with 2 items: `var name:  String` and `var categories: [String]`

Comment: Good point about using a struct. I got this working with dictionaries, but may go back and refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Although Dictionary is not recommended for collection view data sources, in you case you have an array of dictionaries that has `String` as key and `Array<Cat>` as value.

So, if your section title is the one and only key of each individual dictionary your code can work with just a little twist:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].values.first?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CatCell", for: indexPath) as! CatCollectionViewCell
    let section = sections[indexPath.section]
    let cats = section.values.first ?? [] // Here we taking the first element of the `values` collection
    let cat = cats[indexPath.row]
    cell.configure(with: cat)
    return cell
}
```

When you call `values` property of a dictionary you are getting a Collection with all the dictionary values. In your particular case, the value type was `Array<Cat>`, so `values` property is returning a collection of `Array<Cats>` (something like `Array<Array<Cat>>`) thats why you have to take the first element. (and possible the only one)

Respectively, your can have access to your section title with something like this:

```
let sectionTitle = sections[section].keys.first
```